# Клиент не видит Сервер в локальной сети

Tags: c#, клиент-сервер, tcp

[image: Клиент слева - стучится, Сервер справа - ждет]

Сделал клиент-серверное приложение на C# с использованием класса Socket. Если запускаю Сервер и Клиент на 1й машине, все работает, Клиент видит Сервер. (у Сервера IP:порт - 127.0.0.1:8005, у Клиента такой же).
Если на разных машинах (у Сервера IP:порт - 127.0.0.1:8005, у Клиента ip-адрес локальный сервера, порт тот же, например, 192.168.1.33:8005 ).
Клиент не видит Сервера.
Пробовал:
- 2 WinXP на виртуалках (ping есть) -> см. фото
- WinXP и Win7 в сети WiFi через роутер (порт открывал на роутере, ping есть).

Еще не пробовал:
- физические машины соединить кабелем.

Вопрос: Может быть есть какой-то ньюанс (в коде или при настройке сети) при подключении на 2х машинах для выполнения Клиент-серверного соединения в отличие от его же на 1й машине?

Код с подключением приложил ниже:

// Сервер
namespace ServerSocket
{
    class Program
    {
        static int port = 8005;
        static string localHost = "127.0.0.1";

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IPEndPoint ipPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(localHost), port);
        listenSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        try
        {
            listenSocket.Bind(ipPoint);
            listenSocket.Listen(clientsLimitForListener);
            Console.WriteLine("Server was started. Waiting for connections...\n");
```

. . .

// Клиент
namespace ClientSocket
{
    class Program
    {
        static int port = 8005;
        static string address = "192.168.1.33";

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {
            Socket socket = null;
            Console.WriteLine("CHAT\n");
            Console.Write("Input your name: ")
            string name = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

            Console.WriteLine("\nType message and press Enter.\n");
            IPEndPoint ipPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(address), port);
            socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            socket.Connect(ipPoint);

            while (true)
            {
               . . .
```

Comment: `localHost = "127.0.0.1"` Так он у вас только локалхост и слушает, поэтому остальные клиенты из сети и не могут подключиться.

Comment: Вы правы, я видимо думал, что это ip = 127.0.0.1 обозначает, что надо слушать на своей машине указанный порт = 8005 на наличие внешних подключений.

В итоге все получилось, с двумя решениями:

1. На Сервера в качестве localhost указать локальный ip-адрес Сервера:

static int port = 8005;
static string localHost = "127.0.0.1";
IPEndPoint ipPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(localHost), port);

2. Использовать Any:
static int port = 8005;
IPEndPoint ipPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);